# How to pre load Android in-app billing purchases

Tags: java, android, google-play, google-play-services, in-app-billing

I am using Anjlab's IAB library. What is the best approach on finding out whether or not a user has a product prior to the main part of the app loading? My current approach is to have a launcher activity that waits to load products from Google and once it has starts the main activity.

Is there some other method that is recommended instead?

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: I think you can set up a `restore` button for the user when user want to do it, or put that presses in `different thread` that not blocking the main thread.

Comment: @bijang That's an alternative but I'm looking to find the best approach for loading it beforehand.